# Faraday::ParsingError - 757: unexpected token

Tags: ruby, json, faraday

I'm writing an API Wrapper and running into an issue that I'm not exactly sure how to solve.

Here's the Faraday setup:

```
@connection = Faraday.new(url: @api_url, params: params,
                                headers: default_headers,
                                ssl: { verify: true } ) do |faraday|
                                  faraday.use FaradayMiddleware::Mashify
                                  faraday.use FaradayMiddleware::ParseJson, content_type: /\bjson$/
                                  faraday.use FaradayMiddleware::FollowRedirects
                                  faraday.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
                                end
```

This works for 95% of the API calls I'm making - it parses JSON just like I need it to and Mashify's it.  Great.

The issue is when the API returns a JSON value NOT wrapped in a JSON object.  The API call is this:

https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/maxitem.json

I can see this isn't a valid JSON object in jsonlint (screenshot below).

[image: jsonlint]

Do I need to reconfigure a new Faraday instance for this call alone?  That seems somewhat redundant but it's clearly blowing up on the `FaradayMiddleware::ParseJson` class.

My RSpec test returns this:

```
Failure/Error: latest = client.max_item
     Faraday::ParsingError:
       757: unexpected token at '8438316'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the JSON grammar](http://json.org) a bare number isn't JSON, it's just a number.  So yeah it looks like their API is a little inconsistent and you need a different configuration for that method.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions Nick.